# Is it possible to have a nicer error message in Azure DevOps Server pull requests on test build failure?

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to have some information like how many unit tests failed instead of just the error message:

[image]

Is there any way to do it? If not then maybe it's possible to turn off the error message altogether and just have the failed build name?

In the build definition I have a task group that has a Visual Studio test step, no YAML yet.

EDIT: Step YAML

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run IntegrationTests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*IntegrationTests*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: '$(IntegrationTestFilter)'
    runOnlyImpactedTests: false
    runInParallel: false
    runTestsInIsolation: false
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
```

Comment: What does your task look like or your yaml file? Please share them with us and there has a error under that. Or you could use `system.debug=true` to check the detailed log.

Comment: Added a YAML export of the step. There's nothing special going on really, just test execution.

Comment: Just to clarify, unit tests failing is not the problem, I just want to have a nicer error displayed in the pull request.